# type mismatch error while reading stdin lines

Tags: rust

I have no idea why this simple example is not working:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {

    let stdin = io::stdin();

    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(val) => match val {
                v @ _ => println!("{:?}", v),
                "q" => std::process::exit(0)
            },
            _ => println!("ERROR")
        }
    }

}
```

The error is:

```
src/main.rs:8:5: 16:6 error: type mismatch resolving `<std::io::Lines<std::io::stdio::StdinLock<'_>> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == core::result::Result<&str, _>`:
 expected struct `collections::string::String`,
    found &-ptr [E0271]
src/main.rs: 8     for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
src/main.rs: 9         match line {
src/main.rs:10             Ok(val) => match val {
src/main.rs:11                 v @ _ => println!("{:?}", v),
src/main.rs:12                 "q" => std::process::exit(0)
src/main.rs:13             },
               ...
```

I'm just trying to echo stdin lines entered and exit the application if the line equals "q".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler is trying to match `val`, which is a `String`, against the pattern `"q"`, which is a `&str`. This gives you a mismatch.

Instead, write `match val.as_str()` so the types match up. Maybe instead converting the string literal to a `String` would also work, but that would be a useless heap allocation.

Second, the pattern `v @ _` is redundant. You're saying "match anything, and give it the name `v`". But a simple `v` pattern does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation

This slightly confusing error message is a result of Rust's way to do type inference. Rust doesn't know what type `line` has, when it looks at the first line of the loop. So it tries to figure out with the loop body:

```
match line {
    Ok(val) => /* ... */
    _ => /* ... /*
}
```

With this information `rustc` knows that the type of `line` is at least `Result<_, _>` where `_` are types still unknown to the compiler. So it tries to figure that last bit out:

```
Ok(val) => match val {
    v @ _ => println!("{:?}", v),
    "q" => std::process::exit(0)
},
```

The bound `val` corresponds to the first type parameter of the `Result`. So what is `val` here. You match `val` against `"q"`. The latter expression is of type `&str`, so the compiler assumes that `val` is also of type `&str`. Thus `line` has the type `Result<&str, _>` (`_` is still unknown, but that doesn't matter now).

Now `rustc` tries to figure out how to use the result of `stdin.lock().lines()` as an iterator that yields `Result<&str, _>`. This is impossible for the compiler, since [`std::io::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html) always yields `Result<String, io::Error>`.

To get better error messages, you can state the type of the iterator explicitly (in this case: rebind it):

```
for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
    let line: io::Result<String> = line;
    // ...
}
```

This results in

> ```
>  <anon>:12:17: 12:20 error: mismatched types:
>   expected `collections::string::String`,
>      found `&'static str`
>  (expected struct `collections::string::String`,
>      found &-ptr) [E0308]
>  <anon>:12                 "q" => std::process::exit(0),
>                            ^~~
> ```

#### Solution

There are obviously many solutions. Here you can see one that I like, because it helps `rustc` to figure out the type on its own:

```
for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
    match line {
        Ok(val) => match val.as_str() {    // <-- note the `as_str()`
            "q" => std::process::exit(0),
            v @ _ => println!("{:?}", v),
        },
        _ => println!("ERROR")
    }
}
```

*(I also moved the `"q"` arm to the top -- otherwise it's unreachable)*

Answer (score 1):

When matching on a string.. you'll need to perhaps slice it to match against string literals, as you're attempting to match a `String` against a `&str`.

```
Ok(val) => match &val[..] { // <---- note the ampersand and the square brackets with two dots inside
```

Also, once you do this, the compiler will probably complain about your `"q"` pattern being unreachable. This is because your "catch-all" (the underscore) is before the explicit `"q"` match... so just re-order them.

It becomes:

```
match line {
    Ok(val) => match &val[..] {
        // The lines below are re-ordered
        "q" => std::process::exit(0),
        v @ _ => println!("{:?}", v)
    },
    _ => println!("ERROR")
}
```